# Is it possible to add a non-group member to a group project in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

We are a small company that uses Gitlab (free, not self hosted) to manage our projects. We have created our group which has 6 members so far.

We need to grant access to a new user for a specific project, but this user is not part of the company, and we don't want to add him to our group because we are not willing him to get access to all of our projects.

That seems to be exactly [this case described in the doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/#add-a-user) but this option doesn't exist in the members section of the project.

I suspect this is an EE or paid feature, can anyone confirm ? Or hopefully provide a workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

**YES** - The feature of being able to add someone to a single project within a group *but not a group* on https://gitlab.com/ **is a feature enabled for free**.

#### How?

To add someone to ONLY the project:

1. Navigate to the project directly.
2. Navigator to the Members section.
3. Add the user.

> **Note**: You must be at least a project **Maintainer** yourself before you can invite someone else to collaborate. GitLab simply hides buttons you lack access to.

You can also hit the URL directly:

If your group is called `benscompany`,
And if your project is called `operationawesome`,
Then the URL to manage users for that specific project will be:
https://gitlab.com/benscompany/operationawesome/-/project_members

GitLab will "play dumb" if you lack the access, returning a 404 for pages you lack access to, for security purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Unfortunately as I said there is no such option to add a member. All I have is a list of every member of the group, that I can sort and filter, and nothing else.

Comment: Maybe you lack the right access - are you the maintainer or owner for that project?

Comment: Hi @Ben, this is the reason I wrote the note that reads "Note: You must be at least a project Maintainer yourself before you can invite someone else to collaborate. GitLab simply hides buttons you lack access to."